# MySQL selecting from 2 tables with a common, unique value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

**Users**

```
ID     USERNAME
1      bobby
2      jack
```

**Pictures**

```
USER_ID     SCORE
1           44
2           33
```

I want to select Users.username and Pictures.score where Users.ID = Pictures.USER_ID = 1 (Bobby's data).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) like this:

```
SELECT 
  u.username,
  p.score
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN pictures p
  ON u.ID = p.user_ID
WHERE u.ID = 1
```

Also, you might need to [`GROUP`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) the results depending on your relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` to pull the `Pictures` table into the query

```
SELECT u.USERNAME, p.SCORE FROM Users
INNER JOIN Pictures p ON p.USER_ID = u.ID
WHERE u.ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to get data from both the tables and then use where condition to filter out specific user.

```
Select u.username,p.score 
from users u 
inner join pictures p 
on u.id=p.user_id  where u.id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Inner join]

**Inner join produces only the set of records that match in both Table A and Table B.**

For you case, this query will do:

```
SELECT u.username , p.score 
FROM users u 
  INNER JOIN pictures p 
  ON u.id = p.user_id  
WHERE u.id = 1
```